# Starting celeryd & celerycam in production using supervisor failing on AWS

Tags: python, django, celery, bitnami, supervisord

I'm using a Bitnami AMI for a django project that will also need celery and celerycam running. I'd like to use supervisor to start and manage these services, but am having trouble. The config for the two is similar, so I've only pasted celeryd (/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celeryd.conf):

```
[program:celeryd]

command = python /home/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/iris_django/manage.py celeryd -B -E

directory = /home/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/iris_django

user = root

autostart = true
autorestart = true

stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/celeryd_err.log
```

When I try to start it, I get this:

```
celeryd                          FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

The logs indicate that the path to the "manage.py" file is incorrect. But, I'm not using a virtual machine (I don't think) and all of my modules (django, celery, etc.) are installed on the base Python install. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Here's the log info (Django is definately installed via PIP):

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/iris_django/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
```

Comment: Listen to what it says :) **process log may have details**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using django-supervisor for this. It worked like a charm.

https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor